# Java Swing GUI Better Base Layout IntelliJ

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, layout-manager

I have to do a project in which I use GUI. I am currently using IntelliJ.

I'm struggling with the layout design, like where to put labels, text fields, etc.

I can only place them in specific places, and can't resize them when pulling on them. I realized that you can indent from the left in the properties, but that seems to be it.

I realize that I can create multiple different panels, but I fear that I end up with 15 different panels, just to create a simple program. Is it perhaps better to do it by hand?

Does the problem lie in the base layout, or are there other solutions?

Comment: *Is it perhaps better to do it by hand?* Yes.  You'll learn Swing and not the idiosyncrasies of a particular GUI builder.  The Oracle tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will show you the correct way to code Swing.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Comment: 1) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 2) *"I fear that I end up with 15 different panels"* Most GUIs would require less panels than that, but don't worry about 'lots of panels' until there are *thousands* of them.

Comment: Alright. Gilbert Le Blanc and Andrew Thompson,thank you for your response :) At the moment, I feel that creating it by hand is better, and skipping GUI builders. Hopefully, it will work out. Once again, thank you.

Comment: Tip: Add @GilbertLeBlanc (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, alright, forgot about it :) Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: @Mistful *"forgot about it"* I know the feeling! Sometimes I think I've forgotten more than I remember!  *"Thank you for the reminder."* You're welcome. :)